# Batching tasks with Executor

Tags: java, batch-file, javafx-2, executorservice

I want to batch a bunch of tasks (updates to a GUI) and run them every second. (I have hundreds of updates a second and its causing Java FX 2 to freeze up)

```
    public void update(String price){
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                priceLabel.setText(price);

            }});
    }
```

Whats the easiest way of doing this in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Well normally all updates to a GUI are batched together and are processed in the GUI thread. I think your architecture is your real problem. It is not wise to change labels every 10 ms. Even if Java FX would support this, the only thing the user would see is flickering. So I recommend that you update your internal data model and make the changes of your data model visible to the user at a certain time rate. Your data model is then independent of your UI and a background thread could submit a **single** update to your UI every 2 second or so.

Answer (score 0):

What triggers the change? If the text is linked to some object's value, [you could use binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) to get an automatic update of the GUI when the object's value changes.

Alternatively, you can try doing it manually. See the code below for example (which is simplistic - you probably need to clear the list when you run the runnables to avoid running them twice - in which case you need to deal with concurrency issues etc):

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
final List<Runnable> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Runnable>(); //your updates
Runnable updateGui = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (Runnable r : list) {
                    r.run();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateGui, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

list.add(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        priceLabel.setText(price);
    }
});
```